# How to auto install gulp/gulp-sass on VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gulp, gulp-sass

Since i'm learning to code i'm creating new project folders a lot.
Each time i make a new project folder, i have to install gulp and gulp-sass and set eveything up like editing the task.json and gulpfile.js. Is there a way to do this without going through all of the steps at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css every time? I want it set-up for each new project-folder i create by default or auto-installed.